# /opt/cmake/bin/cmake no file in the directory

Tags: pi-4, software-installation, raspbian-buster, qt

I am installing Qt6 using this guide

https://www.tal.org/tutorials/building-qt-62-raspberry-pi

and i am stuck in the ***Configure the Qt 6.2 build*** portion where it asks me to execute this line

```
/opt/cmake/bin/cmake -G Ninja \
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/Qt/6.2.3-armv7l \
-DQT_FEATURE_opengles2=ON \
-DQT_FEATURE_opengles3=ON \
-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=tc.cmake \
-DQT_AVOID_CMAKE_ARCHIVING_API=ON ../qtbase-everywhere-src-6.2.3
```

but i am getting an error

```
bash: /opt/cmake/bin/cmake: No such file or directory
```

I followed every step behore hand and there were no problems, everthing went smoothly exempt this part. Can anybody help me with this problem ?

Comment: This is probably a good time to upgrade to bullseye if you have been considering it, as the author observes *"a custom cmake is not required on Raspberry Pi OS Bullseye. It contains a new enough version."*

Comment: Does your path include /opt/cmake/bin/ ? From my linux experience, I would create a /opt/bin directory, which contains all the optional binaries.

Answer (score 1):

From the error output, seems like bash could not find your CMake installation. Are you sure CMake is already installed in `opt/cmake`? In the guide, the author provided this line on section ***Build and install cmake from sources***:

`../cmake-3.22.2/bootstrap --prefix=/opt/cmake --parallel=4 && make -j4 && make install`